# Wrong Email Error message - By Sendmail unix

Tags: email, unix, sh

Does sendmail command returns any errors if we use wrong email id with correct e-mail id pattern?
If it is not how to identify if e-mail is delievered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Nitin, unix does give an output if the email remains undelivered. you can check in /var/spool/mail/home_dir

For example

```
mailx correct_addr@domain.com -s "Success Tested" correct_addr@domain.com < /tmp/dileep/test.txt
correct_addr@server:
```

you will see the prompt back to you, else look below

```
mailx correct_addr@domain.com -s "Success Tested" wrong_addr@domain.com < /tmp/dileep/test.txt
You have mail in /var/spool/mail/home_dir
correct_addr@server:
```

you can go and check the error message, if you would like to check or automate, you can monitor the home_dir for any mail delivery failures and send one email to you will all the details attached to the email and find out the wrong addresses.

NOTE: This works the same way for To and From addresses as well.